# How do I get a single page navigation depending on the previous page?

Tags: categories, templates, homepage, single

I figured this would be a fairly comon thing. But I can't seem to find out how to do it. Or I'm just not using the correct search terms.

I've got a website with a hompage that lists all my posts, and 3 menu items that each list a category.

When I click on a post via a category, then I want the next|prev navigation to stay in that category.

When I click on a post via the homepage, I want the next|prev navigation to be chronolonical.

This is de navigation code which is in my single.php

`<?php next_post_link('%link', '< Previous ', FALSE); ?> <?php previous_post_link('%link', '| Next >', FALSE); ?>`

This is the correct setupt for navigating there from the homepage, but not when I get there via a category.

Please help, I've been banging my head on this for hours now!

Kind regards.

Comment: `<?php previous_post_link($format='&laquo %link', $link='%title', $in_same_cat = true); ?> ` TRY this

`$in_same_cat = true); ` This will make it work in same category

Comment: @KuldeepDaftary, that should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I was not sure if I was right! :P

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link#Text_As_Link.2C_Without_Post_Title.2C_Within_Same_Category

in same category = true is the trick